# Merge two column based on two conditions with pandas merge

Tags: pandas, merge

This question has been answered with only one condition. How can I join two column with two conditions, in my case date and sku?

Thank you.

```
Example1
date sku loc flag  
2017 122  61 True 
2018 122  61 True
2017 113  62 True 
2018 113  62 True 


Example2 
date  sku dept 
2017  122 a
2018  122 b
2017  113 c
2018  113 d



 Example3
date  sku loc flag   dept  
2017  122  61 True   a
2018  122  61 True   b
2017  113  62 True   c
2018  113  62 True   d
```

> `Blockquote`

Comment: `pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['sku','date'],how='inner')`

Comment: Use `Example1.merge(Example2, on=["date","sku"], how="inner")`